# Regex match not working when string is too long?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string :

```
var example = '{%start%}$MOXDATA${"name":"group one","sections":[{"name":"section one","fields":[{"name":"plain one","type":"plain","value":"// some \"plain\" \'\"\"\"\'\' \'\'  \'    \'  \" \" \" tesP(&^&#37;I&63657riu43r3+_)(I)p;l&gt;:\"&gt;&lt;/&#125;&#125;&#123;|\":1~~``"},{"name":"rich one","type":"rich","value":"<ul>\n<li><span style=\"font-size: 11px;\">{ Lo<span style=\"font-family: \'comic sans ms\', sans-serif;\">rem</span> ipsu<span style=\"color: #ffff00; background-color: #339966;\">m dolor si</span>t amet, consec<strong>tetur adi</strong>piscing elit. Vestibulum ac dolor pulvinar ipsum luctus ullamcorper.</span></li>\n<li></li>\n<li><a href=\"http://retrgfd.com/resrgf\">erwfd\"etrgfdd\'\'refre\"\'\"refrds\'\"\"\"sdgfd</a></li>\n</ul>"},{"name":"repeater one","type":"repeater","value":[[{"name":"plain one","type":"plain","value":"some test value"},{"name":"rich one","type":"rich","value":"some test value"},{"name":"link one","type":"link","value":"some test value"},{"name":"media one","type":"media","value":"some test value"},{"name":"link two","type":"link","value":"some test value"}]]}]},{"name":"section two","fields":[{"name":"link one","type":"link","value":"<a href=\"http://www.yyyy.com\">take me to your leader</a>"}]}]}$MOXDATA${%end%}';
```

And I'm doing `example.match(/{%start%}\$MOXDATA\$(.+)\$MOXDATA\${%end%}/);` which is returning `null`.

However, if I use a significantly shorter version of the above string, as in :

```
var shorter = '{%start%}$MOXDATA${"name""}]}]}$MOXDATA${%end%}';
shorter.match(/{%start%}\$MOXDATA\$(.+)\$MOXDATA\${%end%}/);
```

`{"name""}]}]}` is then correctly matched.

Why is that? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try [`{%start%}\$MOXDATA\$([\s\S]+)\$MOXDATA\${%end%}`](https://regex101.com/r/jF1bX9/1).

Comment: This works! Why ? :-)

Comment: `[\s\S]` matches any character, even a newline. It is a cross-platform construct. In JS, you can use `[^]`, but it is not portable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anony-Mousse answer is good and stribizhev comment too.

However, when you have to deal with a long string, you should use something that causes less backtracking (`[^]*` or `[\s\S]*` will match all characters with newlines until the end of the string and the regex engine must go back character by character until it find `$MOXDATA${%end%}`. That's a lot of work.)

To avoid this work, you can replace `[^]*` or `[\s\S]*` with:
 `[^$]*(?:\$+(?!MOXDATA\${%end%})[^$]*)*`

or more robust (if `$MOXDATA${%end%}` doesn't exist): 
`(?=([^$]*))\1(?=((?:\$+(?!MOXDATA\${%end%})[^$]*)*))\2`

*(`(?=(subpattern))\1` emulates an [atomic group](http://regular-expressions.mobi/atomic.html).)*

In this way the subpattern `MOXDATA\${%end%}` is only tested on each `$`.

Comment: Excellent answer! Do notice that if you're going to use the "atomic" pattern inside a group, you have to increment the backreferences (using `\2` and `\3`).

Answer (score 3):

By default, `.*` will not match *newlines*.

Try `[^]*` to match really *any* character.